# How to redirect URLs through .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to change domain name of my website.

**I want .htaccess to redirect URLs to new domains in such a way that:**

When users click on The URLs like  `http://old-domain.com/my-site-link/` it redirects to `http://new-domain.com/my-site-link/`

and also when users click on URLs like `http://old-domain.com/my-site-link.php` it redirects to `http://new-domain.com/my-site-link.php`

New domain is used and old domain is not.

How is that possible? What will be code to .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both domains are on the same account and same root folder you can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

If the domains are on either different accounts or hosting services you can simple add this rule to the old domain `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: New domain is used and old domain is not.

Comment: @SanamMirza care to clarify? if its not used how do you want to redirect it? It needs to be hosted or parked some where that allows you to use an `.htaccess` on it.

Comment: I have changed domain name. And urls are still indexed in Google as old domain. That's why I want that code

Comment: @SanamMirza that much we understand but if your old domain is not hosted or parked and accessible to you to place the .htaccess how do you plan of using it to redirect the old domain?

Comment: I can park it or redirect it to new one

Comment: @SanamMirza does your host have cPanel? if so you can host your **old domain** on a sub folder of your **new domain** and place the .htaccess on that sub folder and use the above first rule.

Comment: Thanks Dear for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In the old server add the following to the `.htaccess`. You shouldn't need `[QSA]` since you're not writing a new query. `[QSA]` is enabled by default.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you're hosting both sites under the same VirtualHost meaning the old site is not an alias of the new site you'll need a conditional to check for the old site's domain name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old-domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you're no longer going to use the old domain, you should still keep it registered (with your registrar), but set it up as a [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) and you can put the top directive directly into the a server config file like `httpd.conf` or `vhosts.conf` under the `conf.d` directory file (something like this). If you're not managing your server you can usually do this in the backend of your host's user interface or by submitting a support ticket (depending on the host).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /path/old-domain.com
  serverName old-domain.com
  <Directory /path/old-domain.com>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: New domain is used and old domain is not.